# How is Companion different from INSTANCE

Tags: kotlin

How are an object INSTANCE and a Companion object different and which situations should they be used in.

```
ObjectName.INSTANCE.iAmStaticMethod();

ClassName.Companion.iAmStaticMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClassName.Companion` can be used also for accessing a [non static method](https://blog.mindorks.com/jvmstatic-jvmoverloads-and-jvmfield-in-kotlin)

> `iAmStaicMethod()` is a static function and `iAmNonStaticMethod()` is a non-static function.
>
> So, to call the above methods in Java, write the below code:
>
> ```
> ClassName.iAmStaticMethod(); // works fine
> ClassName.iAmNonStaticMethod(); // error: not a static method
> ClassName.Companion.iAmStaticMethod(); // instance method remains
> ClassName.Companion.iAmNonStaticMethod(); // the only way it works
> ```